# What does it mean the prefix "global::" that intellisense is showing me

Tags: c#

In my solution I have a project for the business layer and another one to handle integration; in this last one I have a class to make some service methods invocation.

The Business layer references integration project. There, in the business layer, I have the followig method and when I try to create an instance of the Proxy class, intellisense shows me a lot of "global::". I thinks this global:: makes no diference but **I want to know why the intellisense is showing me that.**

```
public void ActualizarOrdenesDeCompraDesdeElWS()
{
    Integracion.ProxyAudifarma proxy = new global::GOA.Integracion.ProxyAudifarma();
}
```

I guess this is a trivial C# foundation I'm missing, thanks for your answers.

***--Post solution edit:***

The calling was:

```
namespace GOA.Negocio
{
    public class GOA
    {        
        public int ActualizarOrdenesDeCompraDesdeElWS()
        {                       
            Integracion.ProxyAudifarma proxy = new global::GOA.Integracion.ProxyAudifarma();
```

Class GOA being named as the root namespace was introducing an ambiguity risk. Changing the class name to AplicacionGOA solved my problem and now intellisense don't set the "global::" empty namespace prefix.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

Comment: Intellisense feels "better safe than sorry"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just resolves to the top-level global namespace to avoid ambiguity with class names, etc that may clash.

See more here from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx

For example, in your code above if you had a class or member or something named GOA, it would clash with that namespace part, putting global:: in front fully qualifies a namespace from its root in the global namespace.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, it was an ambiguity risk. I was using GOA.Integracion.ProxyAudifarma from a Class named GOA.Negocio.GOA. Changing the class name from GOA to AplicacionGOA leads the intellisense to stop setting the global:: prefix. Thanks.